# Spring Framework: upgrade path for PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to PropertyPlaceholderHelper

Tags: java, spring

I am upgrading from Spring `4.2.5.RELEASE` to `5.0.7.RELEASE`.

### Initial Error

> *The method `parseStringValue(String, Properties, HashSet<String>)` is undefined for the type `NestedPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` `NestedPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java`*

In looking at refactoring the code each change is creating a snowball-effect of errors.

I need some help to understand what I need to do to move change code from using `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` to `PropertyPlaceholderHelper`.

#### The Code

```java
package redacted.primavera.common.spring;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;


/**
 * Extends the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to implement nested resource
 * location placeholders.  Properties from the top-level resources may be
 * used to define nested resources.
 *   
 * @author redacted
 *
 */
public class NestedPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    private Resource[] topLocations;
    private List<String> nestedLocations;


    /*
     * Post-process the bean factory.  Add the nested resource locations to the
     * top-level resource locations before processing.
     *  
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer#postProcessBeanFactory(org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory)
     */
    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        try {
            Properties props = mergeProperties();

            List<Resource> merged = new ArrayList<Resource>();
            for (int i = 0; i < topLocations.length; i++) {
                merged.add(topLocations[i]);
            }

            for (String nestedLocation : this.nestedLocations) {
                String location = parseStringValue(nestedLocation.replaceAll("#\\{", "\\${"), props, new HashSet<String>());
                if (location != null) {
                    Resource[] resources = this.applicationContext.getResources(location);
                    for (int i = 0; i < resources.length; i++) {
                        Resource resource = resources[i];
                        if (!merged.contains(resource)) {
                            merged.add(resource);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            setLocations(merged.toArray(new Resource[merged.size()]));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("", e);
        }

        super.postProcessBeanFactory(beanFactory);
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware#setApplicationContext(org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext)
     */
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    /*
     * Set resource locations and save a local copy.
     * 
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport#setLocations(org.springframework.core.io.Resource[])
     */
    @Override
    public void setLocations(Resource[] locations) {
        this.topLocations = new Resource[locations.length];
        System.arraycopy(locations, 0, this.topLocations, 0, locations.length);

        super.setLocations(locations);
    }

    /**
     * Set the nested resource locations.
     * @param nestedLocations
     */
    public void setNestedLocations(List<String> nestedLocations) {
        this.nestedLocations = nestedLocations;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
parseStringValue(String strVal, Properties props, Set visitedPlaceholders)
```

In the javadoc of version `4.x`, this method was deprecated and removed in version `5.x`.

So, I refactored my code and use `PropertyPlaceholderHelper` as follows:

1. Added an import:

   ```java
   import org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper;
   ```
2. method variable:

   ```java
   PropertyPlaceholderHelper pph = new PropertyPlaceholderHelper(
       DEFAULT_PLACEHOLDER_PREFIX, DEFAULT_PLACEHOLDER_SUFFIX);
   ```
3. Replaced method call:

   ```java
   String location = pph.replacePlaceholders(
       nestedLocation.replaceAll("#\\{", "\\${"), props);
   ```